# SSRS: Default Values for StartDate Parameter Based on EndDate Parameter

Tags: date, visual-studio-2012, parameters, ssrs-2012, default-value

I'm working with SSRS and using Visual Studio 2012.

I have two parameters StartDate and EndDate and I configured default values for each.

The default values currently for both are the following:

```
StartDate: =DateAdd("d",-(Day(today)-1), Today)

EndDate: =Today() - 1
```

I want the values to bring in:
StartDate: 1/1/2017
EndDate: 1/31/2017

Basically, I want EndDate to be the previous day (e.g. EndDate for today would be 1/31/2017 since today is 2/1/2017.)

And then for StartDate, I want that to be the first day of the month that EndDate pulls in (e.g. since EndDate pulled in 1/31/2017, the StartDate should pull in 1/1/2017.)

However, with the current parameters in place, StartDate pulls in 2/1/2017 and EndDate pulls in 1/31/2017.

How do I get StartDate to pull in the 1st day of the month based on the value of EndDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For StartDate you can use:

```
=DateSerial(Today.AddDays(-1).Year,
Today.AddDays(-1).Month,
1)
```

Comment: Yes, it did! Thank you @alejandro! Will accept this as answer shortly when site allows me to do so.